Display x-rows below a certain position from a filtered and sorted list



0
A
B




1
100
start


2
30
8


3
50
rows


4
60
4


5
60



6
60
30


7
40
30


8
10
10


9
30



10
30





In Cell B6:B9 I want to 

sort the Column A in a descending oder and 
display always the number of rows entered in Cell B4 starting from the row entered in Cell B2.

So far I have been able to develop this formula:
=CHOOSEROWS(SORT(A1:A10,,-1),SEQUENCE(C4,,C2))

This formula almost gives me the result.

However, once you reach the point that there are no more than 4 rows below the starting point - which is the case in the example above - the formula returns error #VALUE!. 
The idea is that the formula in this case displays the remaining 3 rows and just cuts out the fourth one.
How do I need to modify it to make it work?

One possible way :


=TOCOL(INDEX(SORT(A1:A10,,-1),SEQUENCE(B4,,B2)),2)


And considering the formula used in the context of the OP, then bit verbose:
=CHOOSEROWS(SORT(A1:A10,,-1),SEQUENCE(MIN(B4, ROWS(A1:A10)-B2+1),,B2))



Return X Rows From Row Index Y of Sorted Data
=TAKE(DROP(SORT(A1:B10,,-1),C2-1),C4)


